# Graph API Explorer's FQL Query: comments_list only has recent comments

Tags: facebook-graph-api, stream, facebook-fql, facebook-comments

I am currently trying to archive a comments thread that is over 10,700 comments long. I am trying to generate the list of comments, so my search query was

```
SELECT comments.comment_list FROM stream WHERE post_id = "<ThePostID>"
```

However, the only comments returned were the most recent ones, i.e. those that you see when you see the post in the Group's Wall. Only the latest 49! Even the `LIMIT 500` hack didn't help. Is there a way to access the older comments?